# Keras - Copy tensor as non-trainable

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm creating a custom keras function (for lambda layers or loss functions) that at some point needs to get the value of a trainable tensor as a constant.

It's for an experimental normalization of a var. I want it to be 1, but it should keep updating during training.

```
def normFunc(inputTrainableTensor):

    #I want this function - here in pseudocode:
    nonTrainableVersion = K.make_a_non_trainable_copy(inputTrainableTensor)

    return inputTrainableTensor / nonTrainableVersion
```

In terms of derivatives, this is equivalent to `anyConstant * inputTrainableTensor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the `K.stop_gradient()` method from the [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/#stop_gradient).

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    return yPred / K.stop_gradient(yPred)
```

Using this loss function will result in a loss value that is constantly 1 in every epoch, even though, the model will keep training and eventually bring yPred to 0 and keep doing it with yPred negative.